# Can I use an If statement inside a While statement?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, while-loop, delphi-7

```
while not eof(MyFile) do
begin
  Readln(MyFile,sLine);
  iCheck := pos('*',sLine);

  if iCheck >= 0 then
    K := K + 1;
  else
    K := 1;
  sLine := sArrayParty[K];
end;
```

`K` is my counter. `MyFile` is set to a textfile.

I am trying to run an if statement inside a while statement to check if there is a `*` in a line read into sLine. If so, I want my counter to be incremented, thereby putting the following text into the next index of the array. So basically I have a text file with information separated by `*` as delimiters and I want each piece of information to populate a new index. But delphi spases everytime I put that if statement in.

Comment: "delphi spases" is not a problem description. If you want help here, you need to **be specific** about the problem you're having. What is the **exact error message** you're getting, and what line of code is causing it?

Answer (score 6):

You have a clear syntax error in your code, and the compiler explains exactly what it is:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(22): E2153 ';' not allowed before 'ELSE'
```

So read the words the error message contain, and remove the `;` before the `else`:

```
if iCheck > 0 then
   K := K + 1
else
  K := 1;
```

The number in parenthesis after the `Unit1.pas` (in my example, `(22)` is the **exact line number** where the compiler stopped working, so the line before the `else` would be line 21. The line numbers at the bottom of the editor window tell you what line that is clearly.

Answer (score 1):

if there is no '*' then the pos function will return 0,
if there is '*' then it will return the first occurance position.

*if iCheck >= 0 then*

should be changed to *if iCheck > 0 then*

Answer (score 0):

i do remember we can assign the string to a string list and assign the stringlist's delimiter property to '*'

ie. 
strlst.delimiter := '*';
strlst.text := sline;

so u can get each string traversing through the strlst...

*(i used this long back,and i dont have delphi now to test it,please correct me if any thing is wrong)*